# What's effective rate when one of the reserves is 0?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, pancakeswap

In this [transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xa6112fd20e50c1442be03a97f4bd8f78cb57008add803f124e6a31ab0d6cf2d8#eventlog), [ECT/WBNB](https://bscscan.com/address/0xad020ca1e74a907b1aa5340d8d09b736b5d6888f) reserves were:

```
reserve0: 0
reserve1: 316227766034
```

given that WBNB/ECT rate is calculated by dividing `reserve1/reserve0`, what does it make the spot price of the token?